# Null check operator used on a null value FLUTTER 2.10

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

I have get this error (Null check operator used on a null value) Exception caught by widgets library when use where condition and order by query together on firebase,

```
result = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .where('place_city', isEqualTo: placeCity)
      .orderBy('likes', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
```

if I remove where statement or order by it will work, like this

```
result = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      //.where('place_city', isEqualTo: placeCity)
      .orderBy('likes', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add orderBy to the query, make sure to check the logs. In the logs, you will get message to create index. Just click on the link and it will lead you to your Firebase Console. There you will see a dialog with the details of the index to create. Just click on Create button. Wait for sometime while the index is created. After index is created, the app will automatically be fine.

Answer (score 0):

After storing the snapshots in `result`, you might be using or trying to access the data, where you probably have used the null check operator.

Please share the entire code to evaluate, or debug the code at the place where you have added null operator.

Answer (score 0):

Before assigning the data to widgets, validate whether that field value is null or not. Only then assign to the widget.

example 1: Validate before assigning the data to widget

```
if(snapshot.data != null) {
  return Text(snapshot.data.name);
}
```

example 2: Handle directly in the widget

```
Text(snaphot.data.name ?? '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because of null safety.

When you add:

```
.where('place_city', isEqualTo: placeCity)
```

you affect `placeCity` to `isEqualTo`, but `placeCity` can be null. That's why you get this error.

To correct this error you have to ensure that `placeCity` can't be null.

For this, when you affect placeCity, do like this:

```
placeCity = something ?? 'default value'
```

You can also, if you are shure that placeCity will never be null use the `!` operator, like this:

```
.where('place_city', isEqualTo: placeCity!)
```

it tell dart that `placeCity` is never null and thus error disappear.